# How to create a how to create a ** GitHub.io URL, pointing to the folder** containing my assignment folder on local desktop?

Tags: github-pages

I have to submit an assignment online which includes - creating a GitHub.io URL, pointing to the folder containing my assignment on github I have made the assignment but failing to submit it because I don't know how to do it.how can we create github.io link and make it point my folder ,and how to create a folder.

Answer (score 1):

open Github.com

1. Click your Name section & Select Your Profile
2. Open your saved **repository**
3. Open PAGES from SETTINGS
4. Then you will get a link with .io along with your Repository Name which you opened on step 3 as shown below
5. Your site is published at https://username.github.io/yourrepositoryname/
6. Copy link
7. Put the path of index.html at the end of the link

> https://username.github.io/yourrepositoryname/module3/index.html

Comment: 3.5 step: enable ".io" a.k.a. GitHub Pages under **Branch** //////
3.75 step: refresh GitHub page/go again to Settings > Pages

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [project pages](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/)

> The source files for Project Pages sites live within the same repository as their project, and they are published from one of the following locations:
>
> - The master branch
> - The gh-pages branch
> - A folder named "docs" located on the master branch
>
> A Project Pages site for a personal account is available at `http(s)://<username>.github.io/<projectname>` .

So:

1. create an empty repository in your GitHub account
2. create a Git repo within your local folder
3. add that repo URL as a a remote and push
4. configure the remote repo publication: see "[Configuring a publishing source for GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/)"

For steps 2 and 3:

```
 cd /path/to/local/folder
 git init .
 git config user.name <YourGitHubAccount>
 git config user.email <YourGitHubAccountEmail>
 git add .
 git commit -m "Add folder content"
 git remote add origin https://github.com/<YourGitHubAccount>/<YourRepo>.git
 git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

The source file for the project and they are published from one of the following locations:

- The master branch
- The gh-pages branch
- A folder named "docs", located on master plan.